# Is it possible to update a StringProperty as it's being typed?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm building some text editor tools. I would like to have live access to a string property as it's being typed. I can assign an update function within a string property but it only updates after the user has pressed enter. I want a way for the update function to run with every key press. Legit ways to do this? Hacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option for this.
Create the StringProperty with `options={'TEXTEDIT_UPDATE'}`:

```
prop = StringProperty(name="Test", options={'TEXTEDIT_UPDATE'})
```

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty