# Update String Property Every Time a Key is Pressed

Tags: python, scripting, properties, panel

I need to get what's been typed as it's happening.

The update function in a string property is only called when the typing is finished. Unfortunately I wasn't able to circumvent that.

So, is there a way to force an update to the property every time something is typed? Or retrieve the value directly from UILayout.prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TEXTEDIT_UPDATE](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=intproperty#bpy.props.IntProperty) option is what you are looking for.

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114614/is-it-possible-to-update-a-stringproperty-as-its-being-typed) for more information.

Comment: Ops, I swear I did a search beforehand :P. Thank you!